# How to get the id of a another resource group in bicep?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep, azure-resource-group

I have a resouce that is called using the uniquestring function of resourcegroup id, i.e.

```cs
var x = '${substring(uniqueString(resourceGroup().id), 0, 8)}'
```

However, I need to use/call this reource in another resource that exist in another resource group.

How can I exactly do that?
resourceId() function doesn't seem to work to get the id of a **resource group**. or maybe I didn't understand how to use it.

I have also tried to type:

```cs
var x = '${substring(uniqueString(resourceGroup('anotherRG').id), 0, 8)}'
```

But this is also doesn't work and give an error.

Can  you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this? Bicep has a way of referencing existing resources.

```
resource rg 'Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups@2023-07-01' existing = {
  name: '<your resource group name>'
  scope: subscription('<your subscription ID>')
}

output rh string = rg.id
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/existing-resource

Comment: Thank you very much @KonTheCat . this solution have actually worked.
```resource moduleRgResource 'Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups@2023-07-01' existing = {
  name: moduleRg
  scope: subscription(subscription().subscriptionId)
}```